# Sort Arraylist ignore digits do it alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

So I got a simple arraylist that I want to sort alphabetically, that part I got down. No trouble there, problem is, there is an ID number before the names on the list. I need to sort it based on the alphabet. Any help is appreciated, see below.

```
    student.add("01, Pentecoast");
    student.add("02, Walker");
    student.add("03, Smith");
    student.add("04, Gonzalez");
    student.add("05, Kylekorn");
    student.add("06, Queen");
    student.add("07, Divan");
    student.add("08, Homero");
    student.add("09, Flanders");
    student.add("10, Simpsons");
```

The way I am sorting is:

```
    Collections.sort(students, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

But them numbers get on the way.

Comment: You can create a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that will split your strings and compare based on the 2nd token.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Start learning. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: The better approach is to create your own `Student` class, instead of using a comma-separated String to represent a student.  Then it is your own choice of implementing `Comparable` in your `Student` (which compared base on name) or make use of `Comparator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a custom `Comparator`, but let's define and initialize your `List`. Something like,

```
List<String> student = new ArrayList<>();
student.add("01, Pentecoast");
student.add("02, Walker");
student.add("03, Smith");
student.add("04, Gonzalez");
student.add("05, Kylekorn");
student.add("06, Queen");
student.add("07, Divan");
student.add("08, Homero");
student.add("09, Flanders");
student.add("10, Simpsons");
```

Then handle `null`, and `split`. Compare the text after the number. Something like,

```
Collections.sort(student, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            return o2 == null ? 0 : -1;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        String[] o1Arr = o1.split(", ");
        String[] o2Arr = o2.split(", ");
        return o1Arr[1].compareTo(o2Arr[1]);
    }
});
System.out.println(student);
```

Output is sorted by name (I get, formatted for this post)

```
[07, Divan, 09, Flanders, 04, Gonzalez, 08, Homero, 
 05, Kylekorn, 01, Pentecoast, 06, Queen, 10, Simpsons, 
 03, Smith, 02, Walker]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for taking the time to actually explain how things are. in the end it helps a lot, i was not sure i could split the string like that. on arraylists. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to compare the names without the id values, you can just substring the portion of the student name you want in a custom comparator:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(final String sid1, final String sid2){
        return sid1.substring(4).compareTo(sid2.substring(4));
    }
};
```

You can sort like this:

```
Arrays.sort(students, comparator);
```

Comment: This was very helpful into understanding what needed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own Comparator that compares the first non-numeric character and sorts accordingly.

```
Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String item1, String item2) {
        return item1.split(", ")[1].compareTo(item2.split(", ")[1]);
    }
});
```